# How to get my Case Statement to Work

Tags: sql-server

Here's what I have so far

```
SELECT DATENAME(MM,dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED)) AS MONTH, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL,
CASE WHEN DATEPART(M,CREATED) >= 10 THEN DATEPART(M,CREATED) -9 ELSE +3
FROM S_SRV_REQ WITH (NOLOCK)          
WHERE (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) >= '11-1-2015') AND (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) <= DATEADD(D, 1, '3-31-2016')) AND (INS_PRODUCT IN ('PS')) AND (SR_AREA IN ('Clinical Question'))
Group By DATENAME(MM,dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED))
```

This is my Case Statement

```
CASE WHEN DATEPART(M,CREATED) >= 10 THEN DATEPART(M,CREATED) -9 ELSE +3
```

Comment: `CASE` needs and `END`, like `CASE WHEN THEN WHEN THEN ELSE END`.

Comment: Slightly off topic; SQL has a [case expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx), rather than a case statement.  Statements are control of flow, often seen in other languages, while expressions return a value.  Also worth avoiding [NOLOCK](http://www.jasonstrate.com/2012/06/the-side-effect-of-nolock/), as it can return unexpected/incorrect results.

Comment: Please google and learn the syntax for CASE in TSQL.

Answer (score 2):

You missed the `END` keyword in the end of the `CASE`

```
SELECT DATENAME(MM,dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED)) AS MONTH, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL,
       CASE WHEN DATEPART(M,CREATED) >= 10 THEN DATEPART(M,CREATED) -9 ELSE +3 END AS CREATED
FROM S_SRV_REQ WITH (NOLOCK)          
WHERE (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) >= '11-1-2015') AND (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) <= DATEADD(D, 1, '3-31-2016')) AND (INS_PRODUCT IN ('PS')) AND (SR_AREA IN ('Clinical Question'))
GROUP By DATENAME(MM,dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED))
```

Comment: @Mel : If this answer is solved your problem, you can accept this answer by clicking the Right symbol below the vote count.